# What pattern(s) does non-destructive badblocks -n write?

Tags: badblocks

[`man badblocks`](https://manned.org/badblocks) says:

> ```
>    -n     Use non-destructive read-write mode.  By default only a non-
>           destructive read-only test is done.  This option must not be
>           combined with the -w option, as they are mutually exclusive.
> ```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280679/143394) says:

> The non-destructive read-write test works by overwriting data, then reading to verify, and then writing the original data back afterwards.

What pattern(s) are used by `-n` if none are explicitly specified by `-t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default pattern with `-n` [is a random pattern](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c?id=75dd3c47c489bef2391bdc147a3f835f1a935fbf#n748):

```
const unsigned int patterns[] = { ~0 };
```

(see [`pattern_fill`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c?id=75dd3c47c489bef2391bdc147a3f835f1a935fbf#n332) for the equivalence to “random”).

In destructive mode, [four patterns are used](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/misc/badblocks.c?id=75dd3c47c489bef2391bdc147a3f835f1a935fbf#n606):

```
const unsigned int patterns[] = {0xaa, 0x55, 0xff, 0x00};
```