# Allow recovery from interrupted `badblocks -n`

Tags: badblocks

[`man badblocks`](https://manned.org/badblocks) says:

> ```
>    -n     Use non-destructive read-write mode.
> ```

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280679/143394) says:

> The non-destructive read-write test works by overwriting data, then reading to verify, and then writing the original data back afterwards.

Is there any way to allow for recovery should `badblocks` be interrupted (eg kernel hang) during or after writing the test data but before it has written back the original data?

Comment: I don't think there's any way. I may be wrong, but it looks like `badblocks` is simply saving the original data into a memory buffer, not anywhere on another disk/partition from where it could be restored in the case of a SIGKILL or kernel hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File systems protect data from a crash with journals, checksums, mirrors, etc. The only option I see for badblocks would be to re-compile it with an option to store the read buffer (and location) on disk, but this would make the tool much slower (and would be bad for a NMVe life if one tried to speed it up that way). The better alternative is to use a filesystem to handle it for you; btrfs and zfs are here for you.

Comment: `btrfs`'s `scrub` will only do a read test. I'm assuming that `badblocks` has two (generally) non-destructive tests (read and re-write) for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Given there doesn't seem to be a way to recover from an interrupted `badblocks -n`:

- I run it only on a disk set with filesystem-level redundancy
- I trust the filesystem can recover should one set of blocks under test be lost